# Mean not working with Gamma convolution distribution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, distributions, convolution

Using v 13.01 or 13.1: bug in integrate, see accepted answer below.

First off, the distribution `Simplify[PDF[GammaDistribution[a, 1/b], x], Assumptions -> b > 0]`
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \dfrac{b^a x^{a-1} e^{-b x}}{\Gamma (a)} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}\;\;,
 \\
\end{array}$$
which is an alternative form of the gamma distribution, when convolved with the same function but with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ yields $$\text{Gdc}=\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \dfrac{b^a \beta ^{\alpha } e^{b (-x)} x^{a+\alpha -1} \, _1F_1(\alpha ;a+\alpha ;x (b-\beta ))}{\Gamma (a+\alpha )} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}\;\;,$$
where $_1F_1$ is `Hypergeometric1F1`. For documentation and application of the Gdc density function see https://ejnmmiphys.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40658-016-0166-z

In case someone wants to try this I have replaced $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that do not render well on this site with A and B here `(x^(-1+a+A) b^a E^(-x b) B^A Hypergeometric1F1[A,a+A,x (b-B)])/Gamma[a+A]`.

Next, please recall that the mean value of a convolution of two density functions is the sum of the mean values of each function (provided they exist), https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/342023/99274, or for this parameterization as each mean takes the form $\alpha\,/\beta$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution),
$$\bar{x}=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\;\;.$$
Couldn't be simpler, right? However, if we define $$\text{Gdc}=\text{ProbabilityDistribution}\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 \Bigg\{ & 
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{x^{a+\alpha -1} b^a e^{-x b} \beta ^{\alpha } \, _1F_1(\alpha ;a+\alpha ;x (b-\beta ))}{\Gamma (a+\alpha )} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
,\{x,0,\infty \},\text{Assumptions}\to \{a>0,b>0,\alpha >0,\beta >0,b>\beta ,x\in \mathbb{R},a\in \mathbb{R},b\in \mathbb{R},\alpha \in \mathbb{R},\beta \in \mathbb{R}\}\right]\;\;,$$
where $b>\beta$ without loss of generality, and then ask for `Mean[Gdc]` without assigning values to the parameters we get of all things $$\frac{(-1)^{-\alpha } \cos (\pi  \alpha ) (a \beta +\alpha  b)}{b \beta }\;\;,$$
which is obviously incorrect as the mean value of definite positive values, as required to define a density, can be neither complex valued nor negative.

However, if we put in values for the parameters of $\left(a=1;b=1;\alpha =\frac{1}{2};\beta =\frac{1}{10};\right)$, which, when plotted `Plot[PDF[Gdc,x],{x,0,10},PlotRange->Full]` looks like
[image]

we get the correct values of 6 for both `Mean[Gdc]` and $\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{\alpha }{\beta }$,
but 0 for
$$\dfrac{(-1)^{-\alpha } \cos (\pi  \alpha ) (a \beta +\alpha  b) }{b \beta }$$

So, obviously, something is wrong, but what? This looks like a bug of some sort. Any insight into what this means would be helpful, in particular, I would like to be able to attempt using `FindDistributionParameters` and am uncertain what I would be getting from that.

**Note** As pointed out by @JimB in his comment below, when $\alpha$ is exactly a positive integer, then and only then does

$$\frac{(-1)^{-\alpha } \cos (\pi  \alpha ) (a \beta +\alpha  b)}{b \beta }=\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\iff\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}^+\;,$$
which is vanishingly improbable for a real valued function.

Comment: @JimB This might be right up your alley.

Comment: `mean = Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0 && α > 0 && β > 0 && b > β, Integrate[x PDF[Gdc, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]] // Expand` gives the expected result.

Comment: @BobHanlon Hummm. I get $\frac{(-1)^{-\alpha } a \cos (\pi  \alpha )}{b}+\frac{(-1)^{-\alpha } \alpha  \cos (\pi  \alpha )}{\beta }$ in 13.0 when I try that. A bug perhaps?

Comment: I posted my results with v13.1 on my Mac. I get these same results with v13.0 and v13.0.1

Comment: For v13.01 on Windows 10 I get $\frac{e^{-2 i \pi  \alpha } (a \beta +\alpha  b)}{b \beta }$ for the mean.  The correct mean seems only to work for integer values of $\alpha$:  `FullSimplify[(E^(-2 I \[Pi] \[Alpha]) (b \[Alpha] + a \[Beta]))/(b \[Beta]), Assumptions -> \[Alpha] \[Element] Integers]`.

Comment: @JimB I'm impressed. Please put in a complete example as an answer, as that may help with debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dist1 = GammaDistribution[a, 1/b];

dpa1 = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist1] // Simplify

a > 0 && b > 0

dist2 = GammaDistribution[α, 1/β];

dpa2 = DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist2] // Simplify;

dpa = dpa1 && dpa2 && b > β;

pdf = Assuming[dpa,
  Convolve[PDF[dist2, y], PDF[dist1, y], y, x]]
```

[image]

```
Gdc = ProbabilityDistribution[
   pdf, {x, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> dpa];
```

As you indicated, `Mean` fails

```
Mean[Gdc]

(* (E^(-2 I π α) (b α + a β))/(b β) *)
```

However, direct calculation provides the expected result.

```
mean = Assuming[dpa,
   Integrate[x PDF[Gdc, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]] // Expand

(* a/b + α/β *)
```

**EDIT:** Note that the integral of `pdf` does not return unity

```
Assuming[dpa, Integrate[pdf, {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* E^(-2 I π α) *)
```

I believe that this is a bug in `Integrate`.  Express the `pdf` using [`WhittakerM`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhittakerM.html)

```
altRep = Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Hypergeometric1F1"][
   "AlternativeRepresentations"][[5]]
```

[image]

```
altRep[a, b, z] // Activate // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

`pdf` is then

```
pdf2 = Assuming[dpa,
  (pdf // FunctionExpand) /.
    Hypergeometric1F1[a_, b_, z_] :>
     E^(z/2) z^(-b/2) WhittakerM[(b - 2 a)/2, (b - 1)/2, z] // 
  Simplify]
```

[image]

The total probability is now correctly unity.

```
Assuming[dpa, Integrate[pdf2, {x, 0, Infinity}]]

(* 1 *)

Gdc2 = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf2, {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> dpa];
```

With this representation both `Mean` and direct calculation provide the expected result.

```
Mean[Gdc2] // Expand

(* a/b + α/β *)

mean = Assuming[dpa, Integrate[x PDF[Gdc2, x], 
  {x, 0, Infinity}]] // Expand

(* a/b + α/β *)
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks for confirming my problem, next step is finding out why, and what else is bonkers.

Comment: I also confirm your solution, i.e., ```mean = Assuming[dpa,
   Integrate[x PDF[Gdc, x], {x, 0, Infinity}]] // Expand

(* a/b + α/β *)``` Still want to know the extent of the problem.

Comment: Wow! What a *tour de force.* I accept your answer and will put in a `bug` tag if you don't mind.

Comment: The bug is still present in version 13.2 (November 18, 2022)